# How should questions about citation managers be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

I have notice that there is a separate tag [reference-managers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-managers) with the following [tag-excerpt](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-managers/info): "Questions related to various reference/citation management software used for recording and utilising bibliographic citations."

However, it seems that some questions about citations managers are [tagged by (citations) and (software)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations+software) instead of (or in addition to) the tag (reference-managers).

What is the correct way to tag questions of this type? Should we use all three tags? Or perhaps [reference-managers and citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-managers+citations) (if [reference-manages](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-manages) would be considered as "a subtag" of [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations))?

Should we add the tag [reference-managers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-managers) to older questions about this topic which do not use this tag in order to make them easier to find? (Perhaps they were asked before the tag was created - or maybe simply the OP was unaware of the tag.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no agreed consensus on this. SE has no concept of "sub-tags", for now. If you are below the 5-tag limit, I suggest using all three, which is the most helpful choice.

If you must choose, I would go with the most specific one, because it looks like the most helpful one to a potential searcher. (In addition, doing this is future-proof: it does the right thing automatically if sub-tags and taxonomies are added to the platform one day.)